# How to know active control within XAML designer?

Tags: xaml, silverlight, design-time

How to know, during design-time, which control is active / focused by the user in a custom items control, so as to show the rendering for that selected item?

I'm after functionality similar to [TabControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol(v=vs.95).aspx):

[image]

The difference in my control is that it displays a very simple, sequential workflow, and will show breadcrumbs in place of tabs.  Currently, I'm just displaying the first panel content of the control.  I need to know when a developer has another panel active in the XAML editor to display content of that panel, accordingly.

I'm currently after a value that would be available in `MeasureOverride`, but would be flexible as long as I have anything available in the code-behind.

I've tried such hacks as

```
if (System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)
{
    foreach (var panel in this.Panels)
    {
        panel.GotFocus += focusHandler;
    }
}
```

and using `System.Windows.Input.FocusManager.GetFocusedElement()` but haven't met with any luck thus far.

Comment: So just to ensure I'm understanding you correctly. You want to be able to grab something like GotFocus event from an object in design time as opposed to at run-time? Are you trying to expand on functionality of the designer in some way? Sorry amigo the way it's worded isn't helping visualize the question I suppose.

Comment: @ChrisW. I have a custom control that provides layout for other controls, which will be visible one at a time.  Right now I can only display the first control in the designer.  I want to display the others, according to when the developer has focus within them, same as TabControl.

Comment: Hmmm, good question so +1 there, I'm not sure off the top of my head, would have to think about that one. However the designer could always just right-click the item(s) in the document outline panel and select "edit template->edit item template" (at least I think that's the path, I'd have to double check the exact verbiage in that context menu but pretty sure that's right)

Comment: @MikeGuthrie: I might be wrong but my understanding of what the xaml designer does (and what it doesn't) is: It merely takes the markup and renders it. But it is not "running" your control or anything that resembles a silverlight UI thread. Therefore your mouseclicks will not setFocus or trigger a button.

Comment: @Martin The designer does run some actual code of your control (easiest example, add `protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }` to your code-behind), and there must be someway of knowing where within the XAML / control tree the user is currently at (see TabControl behavior).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible ways you can approach this:

### The hard way (Visual Studio Designer support)

You best shot at this is to review the [WPF Designer Extensibility documenation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546938(v=vs.90).aspx), and also have a look at how DesignTime support for the TabControl is implemented.

In design time, the Designer has some mechanism to prevent the user from interacting directly with the controls. This is why you have difficulty trying to determine which element has focus.

You can teach the Designer how to provide custom adorners over your control so that user may interact with them via the adorners.

For your reference, the TabControl extensibility modules can be found in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Libraries\Client\Design
- System.Windows.Controls.Design.dll
- System.Windows.Controls.VisualStudio.Design.dll
- System.Windows.Controls.Expression.Design.dll
```

The key idea appears to be:

1. `SelectedTabItemPolicy` lists the types of control (in this case - it is the `TabItem`) where selection can appear
2. `TabItemAdornerProvider` then calls `SetDesignTimeIsSelected` on the selected TabItem
3. This in turn calls:

   item.get_Context().get_Services().Publish(service);

which appears to take a dictionary of values. There are a lot of rabbit holes to explore here.

### The easier way out

You can actually respond to changes in the property sheet. e.g. When `SelectedIndex` changes, you can make the different pages visible.

**Changelog**
Updated with links to WPF Designer documentation.

Comment: I'm after design-time functionality similar to TabControl, but the end behavior of my control is different enough that I'm just starting from UserControl.  Looks like I'll be after doing it the hard way.  I stumbled across those design dlls, but when I add them to my project, they just go away.  I did get some help from Telerik, who had said all their design-time support is built into separate library projects.

Comment: Looks like this is going to be as close as I'm going to get, for now.  More effort than I have time to invest toward this particular problem for just a little, in-house, design-time improvement.  I'll hopefully have some time later on to implement a working solution and add it here.  (Or, as it's community wiki already, maybe someone else will, if inclined.)